# адаптивность изображения по высоте

Tags: html, css, bootstrap5

Изображение должно занимать 100% длины родительского контейнера(получилось) и n-ое количество высоты для каждого разрешения без скрола. Попытался сделать height:89.5vh(не 100, т.к navbar, видимо, тоже считается и есть скрол), но на других разрешениях изображение сжимается). При строгом значении height: 500px у меня изменяется и длина изображения.

```css
html {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  padding-top: 0.9rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.9rem;
}

body {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: black;
  background-color: #fff;
  min-width: 320px;
}

a:active {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-li {
  width: 200px;
}

.dropdown-menu.show {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
  min-width: 200px;
}

a {
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

a:hover.nav-link {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #bbbb;
  transition: 0.3s linear;
}

.container-fluid {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px;
}

.cat {
  filter: brightness(30%);
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="main-img">
    <img class="cat" src="https://i.imgur.com/799M3PL.jpeg" alt="mainpage-img">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<img src="//i.imgur.com/799M3PL.jpeg">
```

Comment: огромное спасибо